# File in Google Drive mounted as Directory in Collab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access a CSV file hosted in my Google Drive in a Google Colab notebook. As described in [the documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA), I mount my personal drive through the Web UI. The Drive content appears in the sidebar (almost) as expected.
Not entirely, however, because the CSV file is shown as a directory in Google Colab.

This screenshot shows the CSV file in my Google Drive:
[image: Google Drive]

I can download the file from Google Drive, and the content is the CSV file as expected.

This screenshot shows how the file appears in the Google Colab file browser like a directory, including a sub-directory `0.0.0`:
[image: Google Colab tree]

When running `ls` on the file inside Google Colab, the CSV file is also listed as directory, including the `0.0.0` sub-directory: [image: Google Colab ls]

Consequently, when I try to read the file in Python, it throws an `IsADirectoryError`:
[image]

Another thing is that there are two more CSV files in the same directory in Google Drive (as seen in the screenshot above). They do not appear at all in the mounted drive in Google Colab.

There are a few questions about `IsADirectoryError`s on SO, but the ones I have found are due to actual directories. As of writing, Google points me to [[this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471366/isadirectoryerror-errno-21-is-a-directory-content-drive-mydrive-plant-toma)][7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471366/isadirectoryerror-errno-21-is-a-directory-content-drive-mydrive-plant-toma), which has apparently been deleted.

Why is my file shown as a normal file in Google Drive, but as a directory in Google Colab? Where does the sub-directory `0.0.0` come from?
Why are the two other files not visible in Google Colab?

Comment: There is also no difference between opening Colab in Google Chrome vs. Firefox.

Comment: It looks like the mount button in the UI is not working automatically at all any longer. Instead, when I click it, Colab automatically adds a cell for mounting Google drive programmatically. When using that, the drive is mounted as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way using os library.

```
from google.colab import drive 
import os
import pandas as pd
```

Mount drive

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Print file names and note the file index

```
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/educational_classifier"
fnames = os.listdir(path)
print(fnames)
```

Output should be: `['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']`

Use the index to read file

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, fnames[index]))
```

e.g : `df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, fnames[3]))`

Comment: The method of reading the file in Python seems unrelated, but terminating the runtime and mounting the Drive programmatically (with `drive.mount()`) instead of through the Web UI (mount button) seems to mount the data correctly. Not sure if this really what makes the difference, or if there was just a glitch in the Google Drive/Colab integration.

Comment: @Carsten Sounds like a glitch (maybe due to large file size; not sure), hopefully your issue was resolved.